# <video> image flip when image is zoomed in

Tags: html, css, image, html5-video, ip-camera

***functionality:***
User to stand infront of camera and take a picture.

***What has been done:***

Made use of of a to capture motion image and have created a "Take Picture" button to capture the image to impose a still image. Have also incorporated a Zoom feature as well.

***Issue:***

Originally, the image is functionally well. Hence, when user moves left, the image in the camera feed will move left too and vice versa. However, when users clicks on the zoom in button, the image in camera feed will flip, meaning, when user moves left, the image in the camera feed will move right.

Hence, what has been done wrong? and how to ensure that when user zooms or zoom out, the image will not flip?
Thanks>

```js
var zoom = 1;
v = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
v.style.left = 0;
v.style.top = 0;
/* Array of possible browser specific settings for transformation */
var properties = ['transform', 'WebkitTransform', 'MozTransform',
    'msTransform', 'OTransform'
  ],
  prop = properties[0];

function plus() {
  zoom = zoom + 0.1;
  v.style[prop] = 'scale(' + zoom + ')';
}

function minus() {
  zoom = zoom - 0.1;
  v.style[prop] = 'scale(' + zoom + ')';
}
```

```css
.camera_feed_flip {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
  /* Firefox */
  transform: scale(1.0);
}
```

```html
<div id="CameraFeed" align="center" style="position:absolute; widths:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=7; top:600px; left:0px; ">


  <video id="video" width="1300px" height="1350" style="position:absolute; z-index:16; top: 600px; left:-110px; transform: rotateY(180deg); transform: scale(1.0); -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);-moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);" autoplay></video>
</div>


<div id="Active_Camera" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: none; z-index=6; top:0px; left:0px; ">


  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="1080" id="photo_stream">
    <tr>
      <td width="1080">
        <button id="CameraActiveButton" onclick="TakePicture()">
          <img style="width: 250px; height:250px" src="lib/Take.png">
        </button>
        <button id="ZoomInButton" onclick="plus()">
          <img style="width: 260px; height:260px" src="lib/plus.png">
        </button>
        <button id="ZoomOutButton" onclick="minus()">
          <img style="width: 260px; height:260px" src="lib/minus.png">
        </button>


      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```